# Subclassing NSWindowController or NSViewController in OS X

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I think I really don't get something about how views and windows are managed through respectively view controllers and window controllers in storyboards.

Here's my problem:
I have a window with a mainView, managed by `myMainViewController`.
All I want to do is to make a button in mainView to show anotherWindow (containing anotherView) and send data from `myMainViewController` to anotherView.
Using storyboard, I dragged a window controller (with its associated view) and connected the button to the window (and `performsegue`).
But how am I supposed to access to anotherView's controls from myMainViewController?

- Should I create an `anotherWindowController` class or an `anotherViewController` class?
- And the second case, how can I access it through `myMainViewController`?
- Should I create both of them, even if I would have nothing to manage about the another window (only its view)?

Basically, the button on the mainView should send an image and a string to another view, embedded in anotherWindow. I'm sure it's obvious but I'm a bit confused with the Apple documentation, not very clear...

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:
1) create new custom view controller ( new class that is sub classing nsviewcontroller)
2) create two properties in it ( one for image, another for string)

```
    var myImage: NSImage!
    var myText: NSString!
```

3) after pressing button, in target, you need create new object of your new class as a variable, and through it access to created properties

```
   var secondController = SecondViewController()
   secondController.myImage = //set your image
   SecondController.myText = //set your string
```

4) and now present your second view controller (using presentViewController), and now you can use needed properties in method viewDidLoad of opened viewController

Comment: Tanks but apparently, using presentViewController is contradictory to using segue. In fact, I finally managed the problem. I just had to implement prepareforsegue in the initial view controller, and testing `if let vc = segue.destinationController.contentViewController as? AnotherViewController `

Comment: Yes this option is good decision if you using visual editor and if your button have to just open controller without any another actions, my method is more   unified..